# Remove texts that are enclosed in square brackets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I would like to know how I can go through a column and remove the strings that are between square brackets.

Example

'String [more string]'

after

'String'

Can anyone help me?

I thought about using regular expressions. However, I don't know how to zoom in. I think it can be done by writing a lambda function.

Comment: It doesn't need a lambda function, the `str.replace` method should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['String [more string]']})
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'\[.*\]', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
                   col1     col2
0  String [more string]  String
```

Observe we need to escape `[` to get literal `[` as `[` has special meaning otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to solve the problem I had with your help.